# How to inject Magento 2 commands in custom command?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, command-line

To whom may concern,

As the title said, I'm wondering is there anyway to inject/call/execute Magento default commands in my custom command?

I'm just another guy who living in Terminal world and I'm exhausted while have to press <kbd>↑</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> for those commands all day.

At this moment, I'm forced to write a bash script to shorten it. So I think it is better if I wrote a custom command of Magento 2 to do those jobs. Then I can just simple use bash alias that command in my way.

For example:

I need to execute `setup:upgrade`, `rm -rf var/generation var/di`, `setup:di:compile` in just only one command and few more thing (actually a lot) after `setup:di:compile` executed successfully.

`setup:upgrade` is handled by this class `\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\UpgradeCommand`

`setup:di:compile` is handle by this one `\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand`

But I'm not sure is it Ok to call `execute()` method in my custom command?

Anyone have any ideas for this situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer is yes you can do what you want.

The Magento console commands are built using Symfony (as you probably are aware).

The following is the example taken directly from the documentation.

Ref: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#calling-an-existing-command

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $command = $this->getApplication()->find('demo:greet');

    $arguments = array(
        'command' => 'demo:greet',
        'name'    => 'Fabien',
        '--yell'  => true,
    );

    $greetInput = new ArrayInput($arguments);
    $returnCode = $command->run($greetInput, $output);

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $commandList = array('setup:upgrade', 'cache:clean', 'cache:flush');
    foreach ($commandList as $list) {
        $command = $this->getApplication()->find($list);
        $returnCode = $command->run($input, $output);
        if(!$returnCode) $output->writeln($list . ' successfully finished');
    }
}
```